# How to link to just part of a YouTube video?

Tags: youtube, youtube-iframe-api

As seen on lots of "YouTube hack" types of websites, this format works for now, but is actually deprecated as of Jan. 27, 2015:

https://www.youtube.com/v/YKIrS8p4MNc&start=41&end=274&autoplay=1

Is there a way that is not deprecated to insert a clickable link like that into an e-mail?  The best official alternative that I can find is overly complex for that purpose, requires me to guess the recipient's optimum size, and may not work anyway if the recipient doesn't allow scripts in html e-mail:

```
<iframe width="640" height="360" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/YKIrS8p4MNc?autoplay=1&end=274&start=41" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Besides, I usually don't *want* an embedded video.  Most of the time, I specifically want [a clickable link like this](https://www.youtube.com/v/YKIrS8p4MNc&start=41&end=274&autoplay=1) so that the text flows well without the break of a video frame:

```html
<iframe width="640" height="360" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/YKIrS8p4MNc?autoplay=0&end=274&start=41" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

All 4 examples are the same video with the same options, except that the embedded frame has autoplay=0 instead of autoplay=1, just to keep it from being annoying.
(If someone knows how to actually embed it here, please edit.  Thanks!)

I'm asking this question here with the `youtube-iframe-api` tag because of [this page](https://developers.google.com/youtube/players/support).

Comment: Hmm, it appears that embedding a YT frame is site-dependent.  I copied the (trivial) markup from [this question](http://movies.stackexchange.com/q/60050), and it still didn't work here.

Answer (score 0):

I see now that this issue appears to be quietly fixed.  Direct-linking to a subsection as shown above no longer displays the message about an old API being deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply clip the video as shown below and then get the link to the clipped video by following the instructions on YouTube.

[image]

Comment: That's only if you're logged into a Google account.  And then the clip's settings are stored as part of that account, with only an auto-generated link to paste into the e-mail or whatever to refer to those settings in your account.  Technically yes, that works, and the recipient doesn't have to have an account, but I was hoping for something that wasn't tied to MY account either.

Comment: But I guess Google's not going to do that, since they've made this method that "does what you want, just use it."  (and gives them another way to track people's interests because you have to be logged in now to do it, whereas the old URL switches could be created anonymously)